# About Vs code and windows update

Tags: visual-studio-code

[picture of the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8v0m.png)
I am running windows 11 but my vs code is asking me to update my windows version  form windows 8 to higher level. you can see the picture in the above image.

And when I try to run and debug my simple cpp hello world program  is showing me a message that says "unable to start debugging. unable to establish connection to GDB. debug output may contain more information[picture of the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUnXA.png)

Comment: Those look like two unrelated questions.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.